# after extending base.html ,my child html thiings are not showing

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

before extending i have checked all connections and file paths but after extending my child codes vanises

## base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles%}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static '/images/icon.png' %}" />
<title>allgood.com</title>
<link href="{% static "/css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<span class="name">allgood</span>
<button class="btn1 ">Resume</button>
<button class="btn2 ">resume</button>
<span class="profileimage"><img src="{%static '/images/profile1.png' 
%}"  style="width:40px;height:40px"></span>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## skills.html

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

 {% block content %}
 <p>skills</p>
 <p>skills</p>
 <p>skills</p>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: But you have not added {% block content %} and {% endblock %} in your base.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `base.html` file should still include a block section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles%}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static '/images/icon.png' %}" />
<title>allgood.com</title>
<link href="{% static "/css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<span class="name">allgood</span>
<button class="btn1 ">Resume</button>
<button class="btn2 ">resume</button>
<span class="profileimage"><img src="{%static '/images/profile1.png' 
%}"  style="width:40px;height:40px"></span>
   {% block content %}
   {% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```